# Эквивалент a||b на PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Как вот такое на php сделать? or или and возвращают boolean;

```
var 
 a = 0,
 b = 3,
 с = a||b;
alert(с); // 3
```

То есть

```
a ? a : b -> a||b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Недавно поднималось похожее

```
// PHP <= 5.2
$c=$a or $c=$b; // "||" не прокатит, для наглядности ($c = $a) or ($c = $b)
// PHP 5.3+
$c = $a ?: $b;
```

Comment: Спасибо, просто спасибо)

Comment: Замечу, что в JS - операция "`||`" - это не "логическое или", а функция возвращающая первый аргумент, если он НЕ `null, NaN, undefined, 0`, иначе - второй аргумент

Comment: @timka_s это не функция.